# How to keep file conversion active when app is suspended

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a file conversion app, whose main job is to read from an input file, process the data, save it in another input file.
This process is already organized as an asynchronous task working on two streams, in orderd to show a live progress bar while the conversion is done.

The issue I have now is that when the app is suspended, the conversion is suspended too, which is a problem since the files involved get quite big and users want to do else meanwhile.

What can I do to keep this task alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Extended Execution API to postpone app suspension:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution